# How would I write this VIM command for `sed`?

Tags: bash, vim, sed, ruby, vi

I have a .csv with special characters that are wrecking an import I need to do.

In VIM, I discovered away to remove the special characters with :

```
:%s/\r//g
```

This removes `^M` from some of my broken lines.

But I'd like to either write this into a bash script, or into my ruby script. So I was curious if there's a way I can perform this special character search and replace in either Bash or Ruby.

Searching for `^M` does not work. And also you wouldn't see this character in any text editor except for VIM.

Comment: The simplest way to remove `^M` is to use `dos2unix`. You will need to use an extra work file in your script.

Comment: Ah, would you know what syntax to use? @AFH

Comment: `dos2unix WinFile.txt LinFile.txt`. Alternatively, use `sed -i 's/\r$//' WinFile.txt` if you want to avoid a work file.

Comment: @AFH Ah yes, the `sed` command is definitely what I'm looking for. But using the `-i` option returns : `sed: 1: "/Users/mycomputer/Des ...": invalid command code e` Which i heard the remedy is just prepending a `-e`. So this passes `sed -i -e 's/\r$//' ~/Desktop/my_file.csv` , *but* the special character isn't actually removed. So no change actually occurred.

Comment: My command above works on Ubuntu. Other distributions may have different defaults for `sed` - Ubuntu defaults to Basic Regular Expressions, which include handling of `\r` and related escape sequences. Just a passing thought: your file isn't read-only is it?

Comment: It also works if you enable `-r` (Extended Regular Expressions), as in `sed -r -i 's/\r$//' WinFile.txt`. You can check different run strings with `sed 's/\r$//' WinFile.txt | od -c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (Fedora 20, GNU sed 4.2.2):

```
sed -e 's/\r$//' <file-in> > <file-out>
```

(Replace `<file-in>` and `<file-out>` with your file names.) I use `file` to check the line endings.

Comment: This works I think, but it just outputs the text in my terminal screen and doesn't write it to the <file-out>, perhaps I'm missing a pipe and some further instruction to do that?

Comment: Note the extra `>`; this is the _indirection_. You can also try `sed -e 's/\r$//' yourfile | more` or _in-place substitution_ `sed -i -e 's/\r$//' yourfile`.

Comment: I know I marked this correct already.. but I just tested this out, and it doesn't seem to move the `^M` from the file..

Comment: If you also have '^M' in other places than at the end of the line, use 'sed -e 's/^M//g' ...'